# How to limit menu parameter selection count in Oracle BI Publisher?

Tags: oracle, obiee, bi-publisher

My datamodel has menu parameter which allows multiple value selection. Menu consists of more than 3000 items. I want to allow user to select only 100 or less parameters. Is that possible and if it is - how to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Say we had a dashboard with an Entity prompt and we wanted to restrict the user's selection to 5 entities or less. We can apply conditions to the dashboard sections that will show/hide a section based on the number of entities selected. So initially we create a dashboard with a prompt section, an analysis section, and an error message section. The backend would look like this:

[image: Create dashboard with 3 sections]

The frontend would look like this:

[image]

Then we would create a new analysis that includes only the Entity column and we set its filter to "is prompted":

[image: Entity condition analysis]

Note that "Entity Level 4 Code" is actually the Entity column. We could save this analysis as "Entity Condition". Then on the backend of the dashboard we could set section conditions based on this "Entity Condition" analysis. For the Analysis section we would set the condition to:

```
ROWCOUNT('Entity Condition') <= 5
```

[image: Analysis condition]
[image: Analysis condition settings]
[image]

For the Error Message section we would create a similar condition except it would be set to:

```
ROWCOUNT('Entity Condition') > 5
```

This would set the dashboard up so that the Analysis section is only run when the Entity prompt has 5 or less entities selected. If there are more than 5 entities selected the Error Message section is shown:

[image: 4 entities selected]
[image: 7 entities selected]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my reports are created with plain RTF templates and datamodels, so I don't use dashboards. Any solution on parameter selection restriction on datamodel level?